# How to check if a SQL Server 'BACKUP DATABASE' query was successful?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database-backups

I am using a module in my c# application to make a backup of the app's database.

For that I am using the following SQL query in my C# app:

```
BACKUP DATABASE [myDatabase] 
TO DISK = 'E:\Database-Backup-(2020-11-28 22 37).bak';
```

This is the code I am using:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("BACKUP DATABASE [mydb] TO DISK = '" + "the path here" + "'", con);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
con.Open();
 
// how do I check here if the query was successful or if it has a return value
if ()     
{
   
}
```

From Microsoft [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0)

> For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the number of rows affected by the command.

What is the return value when a 'Backup Database' query is used (if it returns a value)?

Comment: When you execute the command with the `SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery` method, the backup is successful if no exception is raised.

Comment: In your very simple example of BACKUP command the only possible errors could come from a non existing database or from an error in accessing the output file. In both scenarios the SqlClient raises an exception otherwise the result of ExecuteNonQuery is -1